# Javascript Set image border on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a php script returning thumbnails of images.  The script is as follows:

```
echo '<img class="matchImage" name="matchImages" onclick="clickedImage(this.id)" src="'.$num.'" id="thumbNails'.$filnam.'"/>';
```

The id of each image will be like: `thumbNails00001`, `thumbNails00002`, etc.

The clickedImage function sets the imageId to localStorage.

```
function clickedImage(clicked_id) {
localStorage.setItem('clickedImg', clicked_id)
//Rest of the code
}
```

Through javascript I am applying a border to the clicked image:

```
$('#loaded_img_panel').on('click', 'figure.item > img', function() {
  $('#loaded_img_panel img').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

I am trying to the draw the border of the clicked image on page refresh.  The following is the code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
var selId = localStorage.getItem('clickedImg');
document.getElementById(selId).style.border = "3px solid red";
});
```

This returns `undefined`.  However when I try to `alert(selId)` it correctly returns `thumbNails00001` or id of other images that I have clicked.  I have tried various combinations, by trying to set the class to active, by storing the index of the clicked image and using it to set the border, tried using jQuery methods of using index values on name parameter of the image, etc.  But nothing works.

I am in the process of learning JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function clickedImage(clicked_id) {
//localStorage.setItem('clickedImg', clicked_id)
//Rest of the code
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
var selId = "thumbNails00002";
document.getElementById(selId).style.border = "3px solid red";
});
```

```html
<img class="matchImage" name="matchImages" onclick="clickedImage(this.id)" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" id="thumbNails00002"/>
```

First of all, you are mixing JavaScript & Jquery. You should stick with one, otherwise, you will get confused.

You can try it Jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var selId = localStorage.getItem('clickedImg');
   $("#"+selId).attr("style","border:3px solid red");
});
```

Your code should work in `javascript` too. closing brackets were missed.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var selId = localStorage.getItem('clickedImg');
  document.getElementById(selId).style.border = "3px solid red";
});
```

Comment: i do have the brackets on my original code...its a typo here...as i have other eventListeners set to window on load..I will edit my code to include a minimal example soon

Comment: Can you confirm the localStorage is having the values in the `clickedImg`?

Comment: You can check by `developers tools` in Chrome, press `F12` then on `Console` tab. write `localStorage` OR your string `localStorage.getItem('clickedImg');` after clicking any image as you are storing the values after the click image event.

Comment: Can you vote-up and accept the answer if this worked?